# Проблема с запуском Ubuntu с USB - накопителя

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Ставил Ubuntu на USB - накопитель для работы на системе с Windows 10, устанавливал с помощью UNETBOOTIN скачивал 18.04 love x64, напрямик с UNETBOOTIN , также пробовал скачивать с оф. сайта 18.04 LTS, проблема оставалась - высвечивалось меню выбора использования ОС, после выбора "попробовать Ubuntu без установки" был логотип и загрузка  Ubuntu несколько секунд,  за тем экран темнел но не гас . Буду благодарен за указания как именно устранить проблему и почему она возникла.

Comment: А выбор OS в BIOS с Windows на "Другие OS" вы делали?
Устанавливал месяц назад в полностью идентичной ситуации.

Comment: @Assur , если Вы имеете ввиду выбирал ли я приоритет загрузки системы в Boot menu ? то да

Answer (score 0):

Через Rufus попробуй установить. ISO + FAT32 + USB (см. видео).

Comment: @DRatergs, так по умолчанию формат,  FAT32, и диск в формате ISO, на мой взгляд проблема не в записи, так как сначала всё запускается хорошо, а уже потом гаснет.